# ajax call not working on <td> tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

why ajax call `$.load` not working when i click on `<td>` tag?
here is the script by the way

```
$("body").on("click", ".license-table td", function(){
        console.log('ehhh')
        var pane = $(this).parent('.license-table').data("pane");
        var url = $(this).parent('tr').data("href");
        $(pane).load(url, function(){
            $(".table-content").css({
                height: '500px'
            }).jScrollPane({
                autoReinitialise: true,
                hideFocus: true
            });
        });
    });
```

and here is the Mark up.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="license">
                        <div class="row content-tools">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="options enabled">
                                    <a href="distribute-license-modal.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-dismiss="modal">Allocate Licenses</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="options enabled">
                                    <a href="unallocate-license-modal.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-dismiss="modal">Unallocate Licenses</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <form action="">
                                    <input type="text" name="q" class="col-md-12 search"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin:0">
                            <div class="table-content col-md-12">
                                <div class="inner table-responsive pade-content-big">
                                    <table class="table dtable license-table" data-pane="#license">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="10%">Total</td>
                                            <td width="10%">Distributed</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr data-href="license-details.html">
                                            <td><a href="license-details.html" class="ajax-link black-link" data-pane="#license">Product Name</a></td>
                                            <td>200</td>
                                            <td>50</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr data-href="license-details.html">
                                            <td><a href="license-details.html" class="ajax-link black-link" data-pane="#license">Product Name</a></td>
                                            <td>200</td>
                                            <td>120</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

the `console.log("ehhh")` is show up in my console window, but the XHR request doesnt show up. what's wrong? :(

Comment: what is the value of `pane` and url

Comment: I would guess `$(pane)` does not match any elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.parent()` function gets the immediate parent element. When you provide a selector argument, it filters the result; it does not go up the ancestor chain until it finds a matching ancestor. To do that, you should use the `.closest()` function:

```
var pane = $(this).closest('.license-table').data("pane");
```